# HTML Agilty Pack get specific tag attritubte

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have HTML Agilty pack library installed in my project and I'm basically trying to retrieve a img's src attribute which looks like this:

```
<img src="" srcset="" width="218" height="218" alt="Product Details" class="s-access-image cfMarker" data-search-image-load="">
```

And I have tried something like this:

```
  var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
  htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
  var pic = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@class='s-access-image cfMarker']/img[@src]").ElementAt(0).InnerText;
```

But I'm always getting a null value here...

How can I retrieve img src value with Html Agility Pack ? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"src" is an attribute not an element.

Try this:

```
  var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
  htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
  var pic = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@class='s-access-image cfMarker']");
  var src = pic.Attributes["src"].Value;
```

Comment: Ty so much for pointing this out! It works like a charm now =)

Comment: You're wellcome :)